# Should all namedtuples be in a separate file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, code-organization, namedtuple

I'm using quite a few `namedtuple`s in my Python codebase and they're littered all over the `.py` files. Is it a good practice to extract all these declarations into a separate file or should they stay put where they're used?

In a few cases other modules need to use reference the `namedtuples` in separate modules since that's how the interfaces are defined - they expect `namedtuples`. What is the recommended Pythonic way of organizing the various `namedtuples` especially for cross module references?

Comment: They are not any special than typical classes that might contain a model of something.  Some application stack recommend data classes be located in something like `model.py` or `content.py`, but it is ultimately up to you on what organizational scheme is best for your application/library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thought process used for deciding where to place the namedtuples is no different than the one you would use for any other line of code:

- Modules define logical units of functionality. Certain pieces of code may never need to know about or interact with another piece of code. The identification of these boundary lines are a strong hint for where to break the code into modules.
- Modules encapsulate an interface. They give you the opportunity to define an API through which all other pieces of code interact, while isolating the details of its implementation in the module. Isolating code in modules makes it easier to know where to focus your attention when you want to change the implementation while preserving the API.

Once you've identified the logical units (i.e. modules) and the API through which the logical units will interact, it should be clearer where to place the namedtuples.

If one module, `X` needs to import another module, `Y`, for no other reason than for the definition of the namedtuples, then it may make sense to place the namedtuples in a separate module, `Z`, because you've found a boundary line.

If, however, `X` would need to import the `Y` anyway, then it really would not make much difference if the namedtuples were placed in a separate module, since everywhere you `import Y` you also `import Z`.

Now, it is frequently the case that `X` does not need *all* the functionality provided by `Y`, and so you might be tempted to separate that smaller bit that `X` needs into a separate module. But after a certain point breaking up every little bit into it's own module is craziness -- it becomes more burdensome to have lots of little modules rather than one medium-sized module. Where that line is -- exactly what is medium-sized -- is a matter of taste and what you envision to be the logical units of functionality.